# Generating Certificate Signing Request using Management Console

Tags: csr, code-signing-certificate, spc

I am following

https://godaddy.com/help/windows-generate-csr-for-code-or-driver-signing-certificate-7282

guide to generate a CSR to request a code signing/software publishing certificate.

In management console when I Right-click Certificates, and then go to All Tasks > Advanced Operations > Create Custom Request & Click Next I don't find **"Active Directory Enrollment Policy"** to select.

I don't know Whether I need to download any template or generate some custom policy and how?

I am using windows 8 and my user account is not under any active directory domain nor I administer any active directory.

I am not sure if it is the right forum to ask this question. Pardon me, and direct me to the right forum, if it is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and found the solution on [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2013/10/28/creating-a-private-key-exportable-code-signing-digital-signature-certificate/). Try the following:

1. Instead of selecting **Active Directory Enrollment Policy** select **Proceed without enrollment policy**.
2. Click **Next**.
3. Select **(No template) CNG key** from the **Template** list.
4. Select **PKCS #10** as the **Request format**.
5. Click **Next**.
6. Click the **Details** arrow and then the **Properties** button.
7. Enter a name for your certificate in **Friendly name** box on the **General** tab.
8. Click the **Subject** tab.
9. Under **Subject name**, select **Common name** from the **Type** list. Enter a common name in the **Value** box and click the **Add** button.
10. Repeat step 9 for **Organizational unit**, **Locality**, **State** and **Country**.
11. Click the **Extensions** tab.
12. Under **Key usage** select **Digital signature** and click the **Add** button.
13. Under **Extended key usage** select **Code signing** and click the **Add** button.
14. Under **Basic constraints** click the **Enable this extension** checkbox.
15. Click the **Private key** tab.
16. Under **Key options** select **2048** as the **Key size**.
17. Click the **Make private key exportable** checkbox.
18. Under **Select hash algorithm** select **sha256** from the **Hash Algorithm** list.
19. Click **OK**.

So far it appears to be working. I was able to use my new code signing certificate to export a PFX file and successfully sign an executable.

Note: I chose **sha256** instead of **sha1** in step 18 because [SHA-1 is deprecated](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx).

Comment: thanks @Lee your effort is highly appreciated and it is a great help.
I was not sure whether proceeding without enrollment policy will generate a valid CSR, but if it has worked for you it should work for me too.
I will submit the CSR once I get the required documentation completed and will mark it as answer.
Did you submit CSR to GoDaddy or some other CA?

Comment: You're very welcome. Having lost most of a day trying to figure this out, I felt a little better knowing that someone else might not have to pull their hair out to create a simple CSR.

Comment: I did submit the CSR to GoDaddy. I was trying to rekey an existing certificate. I am hoping to preserve the certificate's reputation. I assume that if I signed my software with a new certificate from another CA, the software would lose all accumulated reputation.

Comment: Many thanx Lee for the detailed description. It worked for me